# Educational: First formating, then partitioning, or vice versa?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I am sitting in IT class, and my teacher and me are having an argument about formatting and partitioning hard drives.

He says, that "a hard drive is FIRST partitioned, and then a partition is created which is formatted with a filesystem."
I said, because it sounded silly to me: "First a harddrive is formatted and a partition table - GPT, MBR - is then set. Afterwards, a partition with an fs is created with a specified size."

Note, I didn't call the FS creation "formatting".

Which statement is right, or what would be the very correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_formatting) Page :

> Disk formatting is the process of preparing a data storage device such
>   as a hard disk drive, solid-state drive, floppy disk or USB flash
>   drive for initial use. In some cases, the formatting operation may
>   also create one or more new file systems. **The first part** of the
>   formatting process that performs basic medium preparation is often
>   referred to as "low-level formatting". Partitioning is the common
>   term for the **second part** of the process, making the data storage
>   device visible to an operating system.**The third part** of the process, usually termed "high-level formatting" most often refers to the process of generating a new file system.

and the Important Part :

> In some operating systems all or parts of these three processes can be
>   **combined or repeated** at different levels and the term "format"
>   is understood to mean an operation in which a new disk medium is fully
>   prepared to store files.

Answer (score 1):

Most people refer to formatting as the act of preparing the Filing System for use on a partition. So most people would say that the disk is partitioned first and then any partitions that require a formatted filing system are then formatted. (not withstanding the Wikipedia entry, I'm only saying what is in standard use).

An MBR is only required if you want to boot from the drive so is optional.

A partition table is, of course, a prerequisite of having partitions. AFAIK, you always need this and while you can replace it (actually it is two tables I seem to remember, a primary and a backup), you would always have one because the manufacturer puts one on at the factory. The only time you would not have one is if both copies have been corrupted.